# upload different files to s3 bucket

Tags: terraform

my directory structure is:

```
--scripts_folder
  --code1_folder
    --abc.txt
  --code2_folder
    --def.csv
  --abcd_tst.yaml
  --def_tst.json
  --abcd_dev.yaml
  --def_dev.json
```

I have a code to upload all folders and files to s3 bucket..

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "data_scripts" {
  for_each = fileset("./scripts_folder/", "**")
  bucket   = module.s3_bucket.name
  key      = each.value
  source   = "./scripts_folder/${each.value}"
  etag     = filemd5("./scripts_folder/${each.value}")
}
```

but my current requirement is to upload only certain objects to s3 as showed below.

**main.tf:**

```
--scripts_folder
  --code1_folder
    --abc.txt
  --code2_folder
    --def.csv
  --abcd_tst.yaml
  --def_tst.json
```

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable by using [locals](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals).

Since the files with environment suffixes are only at the top level, I'd split the work up into three files and resources:

In **main.tf**

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "code_scripts" {
  for_each = fileset("./scripts_folder/", "code*/*")
  bucket   = module.s3_bucket.name
  key      = each.value
  source   = "./scripts_folder/${each.value}"
  etag     = filemd5("./scripts_folder/${each.value}")
}
```

In **dev.tf**

```
locals {
    environment = "dev"
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "data_scripts" {
  for_each = fileset("./scripts_folder/", "*_${local.environment}.yaml")
  bucket   = module.s3_bucket.name
  key      = each.value
  source   = "./scripts_folder/${each.value}"
  etag     = filemd5("./scripts_folder/${each.value}")
}
```

In **test.tf**

```
locals {
    environment = "tst"
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "data_scripts" {
  for_each = fileset("./scripts_folder/", "*_${local.environment}.yaml")
  bucket   = module.s3_bucket.name
  key      = each.value
  source   = "./scripts_folder/${each.value}"
  etag     = filemd5("./scripts_folder/${each.value}")
}
```

You didn't mention whether or not you segment your Terraform environments via directories or other means. This gets the job done with everything in one directory.

Comment: apologies for the confusion. i will edit the question for better and simple understanding.